# Adding custom names for vertices

Tags: julia, lightgraphs

I want to create a graph with custom vertex names. Is this possible with MetaGraphs.jl ?

```
using MetaGraphs
using LightGraphs
using GraphPlot

# Create empty graph
gm = MetaGraph()

# Add vertices with properties
add_vertex!(gm, :A, [7.2,8.6])
add_vertex!(gm, :B, [3.2,6.7])
add_vertex!(gm, :C, [6.3,3.9])
add_vertex!(gm, :D, [2.4,6.7])

gplot(gm, nodelabel = vertices(gm))
```

However is it possible for the vertex to have a name called `:A` instead of `1`. Since in the next step I want to add an edge `add_edge!(gm, :A,:B)` (This is incorrect, currently the names of the nodes 1,2,3... , so the way to create an edge is `add_edge!(gm, 1,2)`)

[image]

In otherwords have A,B,C, ... instead of 1,2,3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use `set_indexing_prop!` like so:

```
g = MetaGraph(path_graph(3))
set_prop!(g, 1, :name, 'a')
set_prop!(g, 2, :name, 'b')
set_prop!(g, 3, :name, 'c')
set_indexing_prop!(g, :name)
```

Then, you can refer to the names and they will be translated into vertex indices, which are integers:

```
g['a', :name]  # returns 1
g['b', :name]  # returns 2
g['c', :name]  # returns 3
has_edge(g, g['b', :name], g['c', :name])  # returns true
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, one way to do that in `MetaGraphs.jl` is to define an "indexing property", for instance `:name`, which would contain `:A`, `:B`, etc.

Then, you can add an edge using the syntax `add_edge!(gm, gm[:A, :name], gm[:B, :name])` if my memory serves me. As for plotting, you can simply retrieve the property with `get_prop`.